# Pass multiple array php data into python for use

Tags: python, php

I have a multiple array of $dataraw from the code below

```
$_SESSION['image'];

$dataraw = $_SESSION['image'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dataraw);
echo '</pre>';
```

print_r($dataraw); output looks like this :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["FileName"]=>
    string(19) "20221227_202035.jpg"
    ["Model"]=>
    string(8) "SM-A528B"
    ["Longitude"]=>
    float(106.524251)
    ["Latitude"]=>
    float(-6.367665)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["FileName"]=>
    string(19) "20221227_202157.jpg"
    ["Model"]=>
    string(8) "SM-A528B"
    ["Longitude"]=>
    float(106.9522428)
    ["Latitude"]=>
    float(-6.984758099722223)
  }
}
```

As you can see, its a multiple array of data.
Then i have a button click run python

```
$dataraw = $_SESSION['image'];
$datagambar = json_encode($dataraw);
$escaped_json = escapeshellarg($datagambar);

if(isset($_POST['runpython'])){ 
   echo shell_exec('D:\xampp\htdocs\Klasifikasi_KNN\admin\Klasifikasi.py'.$escaped_json);
    print("success");
    unset($_SESSION['image']);

}
```

This is my python script to call it back

```
escaped_json = sys.argv[1] 
parsed_data = json.loads(escaped_json) 
print (parsed_data[0])
```

How to pass the multiple array of data to python side? and calls it in python? i need the data for python to operate.

parsed_data = json.loads(escaped_json)
Seems give error

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Encode your data in JSON and pass it to the STDIN of py-script in some form of `$py = popen('/path/to/py', 'w'); fwrite( $py, json_encode($dataraw) );` Read and decode that JSON in your py-script.

Comment: Thankyou for replying, Can it be done like this?
$datagambar = json_encode($dataraw);
$escaped_json = escapeshellarg($datagambar); echo shell_exec('path.py'.$escaped_json);

Comment: It can, but i don't think passing a possibly very long string as a command line arg is a good idea. Alternatively you might use a temp file and pass its name as an arg. Still using STDIN fits the best here imho.

Comment: Thankyou glad im still right on track, its okay i just want it to work first. Performance wise not for now xD.